# How can I parent multiple meshes to one bone?

Tags: armature, bones, parent

I have a very many objects in my object tree. How can I select them all and parent them to my Root bone?

They are children of the armature, but they're not connected to the root bone.

I've tried to: Press A, Enter Edit mode, Press A again, And then assign the root bone from the vertex group. But somehow this doesnt work, they wont get connect. But when i do it one object at a time, it works...

Comment: Select the objects, then select the armature and go into pose mode. Select the bone you want. Ctrl-P > Bone. You're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as explained by Jaroslav, the basic way to do it is to switch your armature to *Pose* mode, then select your object, select the bone you want to parent to, and parent with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Bone*.

You also have this solution, better if you'll need to join the objects or some other cases, so it really depends on the situation:

- First deparent the objects from the armature. If you want to deparent several objects at once, select all your objects, select one last (make it the active one), deparent it, then in the *Properties* panel > *Object > Relations*, right click on the *Parent* field and choose *Copy To Selected*.
- Now select your objects and parent to the armature *With Empty Groups*, which means that each object will have vertex groups created with the names of the bones, except none of these groups are assigned to vertices yet.
- Then select each of your object, go in *Edit* mode, and in the *Properties panel > Data > Vertex Groups*, assign to the object the group it is supposed to be part of, meaning the bone it is supposed to be controlled by (it looks like it's the root you want).

[image]

Comment: With more complicated meshes there will be a huge performance hit with this setup. All the object vertices need to be deformed with the bones. Parenting the object to the bone with regular parent, without vertex groups or armature modifiers only transforms the objects world matrix, which is orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: I thought it might be cleaner, please propose your own solution as an answer  ;)

Comment: I'd be just citing the manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html#bone-parent.

Comment: yes I know you can do it this way and it will work but in my opinion it's safer with vertex groups (can't cite precise case right now)

Comment: Yup a case would be an export for a game engine, then it needs to be indeed skinned geo.

Comment: BIG THANKS guys. What I did wrong was selecting "with empty groups" instead of "bone" after I had pressed ctrl+P...

Comment: This seemes to work in Blender, but once I import it to UE4, the connection between the parts and the root bone gets lost. UE4 then creates one bone for every mesh which is supposed to be connected to the root bone...

Comment: Im trying to rig a vehicle for UE4.
In Blender: When I look at my wheels  (which has the correct sort of parenting) in the object editor window, under relations it says "parent type: Object" and under all the other objects which I wanna parent to the root it says "Parent Type: Bone". this seems to become a problem when importing to UE4.

Comment: I don't know anything about UE4, maybe create a question with this specific question   ;)